# Show recent posts from excluded category

Tags: wp-query

I want to exclude category posts from index & archive pages, so I wrote this script in `functions.php`:

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-33799' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

Everything works fine till here, but I need to show the latest posts from this category in a box on all pages:

```
$args = array ( 'category' => "33799", 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
$recentposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $recentposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "news_thumb", TRUE ) ) {
        $img = get_post_custom_values( "news_thumb", $post->ID );
    } else {
        $img = 'images/no_pic.jpg';  
    }
    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "news_short_content", TRUE ) ) {
        $content = get_post_custom_values( "news_short_content", $post->ID );
    } else {
        $content = '';   
    }           
    ?>
    SHOW_SOMETHING_IN_LOOP
    <?php 
endforeach;
```

When I add this script to `header.php`, I get the wrong output. I can understand why this is happening, because I excluded the category in the query, but how can I fix this?

Comment: `if ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive()  )` should be `if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && (  $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() ) )`

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks a lot ! problem solved , but i can't understand what happened?
when this function return true why we should use it in condition ? and why problem solved , can you help me to find out this question please ?
i read this article : [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query)
but still can't understand :)

Comment: `is_main_query()` only returns true in the main query. `pre_get_posts` alters all queries back end and front end, there is no destingtion between queries. Because you only want to target the main query with `pre_get_posts`, and not all the other queries, you need exclude all other queries by checking if the current query is the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Pieter Goosen solved the issue with with this suggestion.

> ```
> if ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() )
> ```
>
> Should be:
>
> ```
> if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() ) )
> ```

Then explains why this solution worked:

> `is_main_query()` only returns true in the main query. `pre_get_posts`
>   alters all queries back end and front end, there is no designation
>   between queries. Because you only want to target the main query with
>   `pre_get_posts`, and not all the other queries, you need exclude all
>   other queries by checking if the current query is the main query.